# Notificação com som em Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Estou com um problema ao fazer um aplicativo semelhante à um alarme. Ocorre é que não consigo achar alguma forma do usuário selecionar uma música em sua biblioteca e utiliza-la quando tocar uma notificação. É possível isso em Swift?

O que implementei foi um trecho que carrega um arquivo de som interno, mas gostaria de pegar uma música da biblioteca:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Late wake up call"
content.body = "The early bird catches the worm, but the second mouse gets the cheese."
content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm" 

content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: "my-music.mp3");
```

Outra questão é que não achei algo relacionado ao alarme do iOS, em que ele abre uma tela com um botão PARAR ou ADIANTAR mesmo estando em background. Em Swift isso é possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os sons das notificações (locais ou remotas) tem o objetivo de ser um alerta, por isso tem restrições:

- Arquivo de audio em aiff, wav, ou caf (nas codificações Linear PCM, MA4 (IMA/ADPCM), µLaw ou aLaw);
- Estar no Bundle do aplicativo ou na pasta Library/Sounds do container;
- Ter menos de 30 segundos;

Documentação: [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW10)

---

Sobre o alarme do iOS, ainda não existe a possibilidade de exibir conteúdo na tela bloqueada como a Apple faz.

Todos os aplicativos de alarme que testei **não** deixam o iOS bloquear, apenas apagam a tela. Se quiser seguir esse caminho, dê uma olhada nas propriedades:

- `UIApplication > isIdleTimerDisabled`;
- `UIDevice > proximityMonitoringEnabled`;

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas informações, só uma dúvida. Tem um aplicativo chamado "Despertador para mim", ele deixa eu carregar uma música da minha biblioteca como toque. Mas isso só funciona quando o app estiver aberto, caso eu deixar em background a música não funciona. Então o processo que ele faz é chamar um método específico que toque a música, através de um scheduler?

Comment: Isso, só vai funcionar se o aplicativo estiver rodando, se estiver em background não funciona. Se quiser pode até usar a notificação pra agendar, quando receber a notificação você toca a música.